# Doubt in probability calculation.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> X and Y are two chess players:

- The probability of X winning a particular game against Y is $1/3$ and probability of Y winning the game is $2/3$.
- They play a series of games in which rules are such that X wins two consecutive games then X wins the series and Y wins the series is when it wins $4$ consecutive games.
- They start the game and play until one of them wins the series.

> Following these rules, what is the probability of Y winning the series ?.

I calculated the probability considering $4/5/6$ total games individually but couldn’t find any pattern so that I can sum it to $n$ number of games and tend $n$ to infinity$\ldots$ thats my basic approach in such problems but couldn’t do here$\ldots$

Comment: This can be solved using a Markov chain. The states are the "consecutive score" of X vs Y (2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4) the transitions are either to 0 in case the streak is broken or towards victory if not, and you need to find the probability of absorbing in 2 and in -4.

Comment: Easiest, I think, is to do it with state variables.  Define states by the length oof the current streak.  That is, let $S_{i,0}$ denote the state in which player $x$ has won the last $i$ games (but not the last $i+1$) and similarly $S_{0,j}$ denotes the state in which $y$ has won the last $j$ games but not the last $j+1$.  Similarly, let $p_S$ denote the probability of  $y$ winning from state $S$.  Derive some linear equations satisfied by the unknowns $\{p_S\}$ and solve.

Comment: @YJT If X wins the first game and Y wins the second then Y already has $1$ consecutive win at the start of the third game. We start in state $0$ but I don't think we ever visit it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonterminal states are $w\in\{\emptyset, X, Y, YY, YYY\}$, where the name $w$ expresses the last relevant wins. For each of these states $w$ we have a probability $p_w$ that $Y$ wins the *series*. For these probabilities we have the following equations:
$$\eqalign{p_{\emptyset}&={2\over3}p_{Y}+{1\over3}p_{X}\cr
p_{Y}&={2\over3}p_{YY}+{1\over3}p_{X}\cr
p_{YY}&={2\over3}p_{YYY}+{1\over3}p_{X}\cr
p_{YYY}&={2\over3}+{1\over3}p_{X}\cr
p_{X}&={2\over3}p_{Y}\cr}$$
E.g., when we are in state $YY$, player $Y$ wins the *series* with probability $p_{YY}$. In the next game $Y$ wins with probability ${2\over3}$ and we are then in state $YYY$, and $Y$ loses with probability ${1\over3}$, and we are then in state $X$. In this way we obtain the equation $p_{YY}={2\over3}p_{YYY}+{1\over3}p_{X}$.

Solving this system gives the initial probability $$p_{\emptyset}={64\over129}\ .$$

Comment: Sir I am having difficulty in understanding your equations..if p(y) is the probability that last win is of y(y has one win in stock) then according to me p(yy) should be 2/3p(y)+1/3p(yyy)..where p(yyy) will denote the probability p has three wins in stock..                        I am confused between your definition of p(w) and the equations...please help.

Comment: Understood perfectly thanks a lot sir.